# what is the meaning of ">" in the return

Tags: c++

I want to ask what is the meaning of ">" in the return

For example

```
  bool Product::is_better_than(Product b) const
   {
     if (price == 0) return true;
     if (b.price == 0) return false;
     return score / price > b.score / b.price;
   }
```

Comment: `>` has the same meaning here as in an expression.

Comment: This tells me that you need to spend time learning the basic syntactial structure of c++.  You are shortchanging yourself if you don't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 return score / price > b.score / b.price;
```

functionally, it is the same as:

```
if ( score / price > b.score / b.price)
{
   return true;
}
else
{
   return false;
}
```

shorthand expression. Also same as:

```
return (score / price > b.score / b.price);
```

Comment: it's not the same as the `if` expression, though will have the same effect.

Answer (score 3):

`>` stands for **greater than**. It's a boolean operator which returns:

- `true` if the first operand (`score / price`) is greater than the second operand (`b.score / b.price`).
- `false` if the first operand is less or equal the second operand.

Since `/` has priority over `>` you could also write.-

```
return (score / price) > (b.score / b.price);
```

To keep your code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Result of logical statements such as `x > y` are `bool`. Therefore,

```
score / price > b.score / b.price
```

checks if left handed term is greater than the right handed term or not. If it is, the result is `true` otherwise `false`.

After determining the result, it returns that boolean.

Answer (score 0):

It is same comparison as anywhere else, function will return true if `score/price` is greater than `b.score/b.price`.

Answer (score 0):

It means greater than.  like 5 > 4